# Is it legal to use the name of an existing GPL-2.0 program, in my own open source project?

Tags: gpl-2

I've created some opensource, free to use Javascript tool. Currently, my program operates under a different name(which i want to change).

This tool is rather similar to an existing one, **that was deprecated** by the creators(Their site clearly states "DEPRECATED", and recommends some other tool, to be used instead).

Is it legal/safe to use the same name? Does contacting the company by email, asking for their written permission, have any legal validity?

I will note, that i'm not a US/Canada/EU citizen(assuming that matters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it.  Using an existing name most likely is a very bad idea unless you get the consent of the people who use(d) the name before; the name might be a registered trademark and you might get into legal trouble.

If it is not the same product, a different name is also a courtesy for the customers to allow distinction of the different products.

And even if you fork an existing yet abandoned open source programme (thus in a way continue an existing project), it is at least common courtesy to choose a different name if you have no consent from the original authors to continue the project. Additionally: the legal argument about registered name(s) from my first paragraph might also apply here.

Choosing a new name is very common: Libre Office vs. Open Office. Kallithea vs. Rhodecode. Jenkins vs. Hudson. Redmine vs. OpenProject. OwnCloud vs. NextCloud. There likely are many more.

Comment: So i better stick to my initial name :D

Comment: @i.brod Or choose a name that makes it clear there is a difference. E.g. FreeDOS is not the same as MS-DOS, but the names are similar enough to make it obvious that one serves a similar purpose to the other.